# (pandas)I want add to count,percent at groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

> i do road csv file's and grouping 2 headers in csv file so i want to
>   each other count about 1 headers value and percent count/total and add
>   dataframe
>
> have a lot of data in test.csv

```
==example==
country city   name
KOREA   busan  Kim
KOREA   busan  choi
KOREA   Seoul  park
USA     LA     Jane
Spain   Madrid Torres
(name is not overlap)
==========

csv_file = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
need_group = csv_file.groupby(['category','city names'])
```

**returns**

```
                               country                                   city names                                                  
0                              KOREA                                   Seoul, Busan, ...
1                              KOREA                                   Daegu, Seoul
2                              USA                                     LA, New York...
2                              USA                                     LA, ...
```

**want to**
- count is cf name's

```
                               country                                 city names         count   percent                                               
0                              KOREA                                   Seoul                2       20%
1                              KOREA                                   Daegu                1       10%
2                              USA                                     LA                   2       20%
3                              USA                                     New York             1       10%
4                              Spain                                   Madrid               4       40%
```

Comment: Honestly, if you want other people to help you, you should at least have the politeness to write proper sentences with punctuation and proper capitalization. Besides that, it is very hard to understand, what your problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll ask questions according to your advice  and help others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need counts per `country` and `name` by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and then percentage divide by length of `DataFrame`:

```
print (csv_file)
  country    city    name
0   KOREA   busan     Kim
1   KOREA   busan   Dongs
2   KOREA   Seoul    park
3     USA      LA    Jane
4   Spain  Madrid  Torres

df = csv_file.groupby(['country','city']).size().reset_index(name='count')
df['percent'] = df['count'].div(df['count'].sum()).mul(100)
```

Comment: thank u so much jezrael but i need percent is value/total –
ex) index[0] percent is 1/5 so 20%

Comment: @Kim - Can you check now?

Comment: I check modify your answer it's percent about cities count but i want to percent about count/total_count

Comment: OK!! I will Thank you so much

Comment: Can you help me "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61948323/how-to-make-pie-chart-with-groupby-result-of-pandas-and-append-it-to-excel"?